# How to use typescript mapping for ElasticSearch response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, elasticsearch, nestjs

How do I set the Post SearchResult interface to the search return value

I can't set the interface to get the return results
You can review the code below

***dependencies***

```bash
   "@nestjs/elasticsearch": "^8.1.0",
   "@elastic/elasticsearch": "^8.2.1",
   "@types/elasticsearch": "^5.0.40",
```

***interface Post***

```js
export interface PostSearchResultInterface {
    hits: {
        total: {
            value: number;
        };
        hits: Array<{
            total: {
                value: number;
            }
            _source: PostSearchBodyInterface;
        }>;
    };
}
```

***code***

```js
     const  search  = await this.elasticsearchService.search<PostSearchBodyInterface>({
                index: this.index,
                from: offset,
                size: limit,
                body: {
                    query: {
                        bool: {
                            should: {
                                multi_match: {
                                    query: text,
                                    fields: ['title', 'story', 'other_titles']
                                }
                            },
                            filter: {
                                range: {
                                    id: {
                                        gte: startId
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                    },
                    sort: {
                        id: {
                            order: 'asc'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }) ;


             // error here 
            let count = search.hits.total.value
           
            const hits = search.hits.hits;
            const results = hits.map((item) => item._source);
            return {
                count : startId ? separateCount : count,
                results
            }
```

error TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'number | SearchTotalHits'.
Property 'value' does not exist on type 'number'.

```js
ERROR: let count = search.hits.total.value
```

Comment: are you sure that elasticsearch is not reurning any error in response and search is returning 200 response code ?

Comment: yes if i skip the interface it's run
but it's not recognize interface

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming dependencies are (as question posted) :

```json
"@nestjs/elasticsearch": "^8.1.0",
"@elastic/elasticsearch": "^8.2.1",
"@types/elasticsearch": "^5.0.40",
```

First, create a dedicated type for the indexed document, for example :

```js
export type Document = { 
  title: string, 
  tags: string[]
};
```

Then, simply search for documents :

```js
const a = await this.elastic.search<Document>({ //...request... });

const total = a.hits.total;
const documents = a.hits.hits.map(document => {
  // query metadata fields returned by elastic
  document._id;

  // get fields for <Document> type
  document._source.title...
  document._source.tags...
})
```